# Can't rebuild electron with sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, electron, electron-rebuild

I've been trying to solve this problem for over a week now, but I still can't figure out how to solve it. I want to create a database for one of my desktop apps build with electron. So I've installed slqite3 and electron-rebuild (latest version). When I try to rebuild the app, the following erro occurs:

```
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\maart\OneDrive\Bureaublad\DataKicks_App\node_modules\sqlite3'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
```

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this problem?